# selecting random lines from huge text file

Tags: java

I have very huge text file 18000000 line 4Gbyte, and I want to pick some random lines from it, I wrote the following piece of code to do this  but it is slow

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int sampleSize =3000;
        int fileSize = 18000000;
        int[] linesNumber = new int[sampleSize];
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < linesNumber.length; i++) {
            linesNumber[i] = r.nextInt(fileSize);

        }
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(linesNumber).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        Collections.sort(list);

        BufferedWriter outputWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("output.txt"));

        for (int i : list) {

            try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("huge_text_file"))) {
                String en=enlines.skip(i-1).findFirst().get();

                outputWriter.write(en+"\n");
                lines.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);

            }

        }
        outputWriter.close();


    }
}
```

is there more elegant faster method to do this?
thanks.

Comment: This may be a code-review type question -- I don't really know for sure.

Comment: If this code works fine, then this question is off topic on Stack Overflow, but may be good for our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things that I find troublesome about your current code.

1. *You are currently loading the entire file into RAM*. I don't know much about your sample file, but the one I used crashed my default JVM.
2. *You are skipping the same lines over and over again*, more so for the earlier lines - this is horribly inefficient, like O(n^n) or something. I would be surprised if you could handle even a 500MB file with that approach.

Here's what I came up with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int sampleSize = 3000;
    int fileSize = 50000;
    int[] linesNumber = new int[sampleSize];
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < linesNumber.length; i++) {
        linesNumber[i] = r.nextInt(fileSize);

    }
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(linesNumber).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.sort(list);

    BufferedWriter outputWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("localOutput/output.txt"));
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("extremely large file.txt")))
    {
        int index = 0;//keep track of what item we're on in the list
        int currentIndex = 0;//keep track of what line we're on in the input file
        while(index < sampleSize)//while we still haven't finished the list
        {
            if(currentIndex == list.get(index))//if we reach a line
            {
                outputWriter.write(reader.readLine());
                outputWriter.write("\n");//readLine doesn't include the newline characters
                while(index < sampleSize && list.get(index) <= currentIndex)//have to put this here in case of duplicates in the list
                    index++;
            }
            else
                reader.readLine();//readLine is dang fast. There may be faster ways to skip a line, but this is still plenty fast.
            currentIndex++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    outputWriter.close();
    System.out.println(String.format("Took %d milliseconds", System.currentTimeMillis() - t1));
}
```

This takes ~87 milliseconds for me on a 4.7GB file running with a sample size of 30 and filesize of 50000 and took ~91 milliseconds when I changed the sample size to 3000. It took 122 milliseconds when I increased the filesize to 10,000. Tl;Dr for this paragraph = it scales pretty well, and it scales extremely well with larger sample sizes.

In direct answer to your question "is there more elegant faster method to do this?" Yes, there is. **The faster way to do it is to skip lines yourself, don't load the entire file into memory, and make sure to keep using buffered readers and writers.** Also, I'd avoid trying to do your own raw Array buffers or anything like that - just don't.

Feel free to step through the method I've included if you want to see more of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

My first cut at an approach would be to have a look at RandomAccess files in Java cf.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html.  Typically random seeks will be a lot faster than reading the whole file, but you'd then need read byte by byte to get to the beginning of the next line (for example), then read that line in byte by byte to the next newline, then seek to another random location.

I'm not sure the approach would be more elegant (depends partly on how you code it I guess), but I'd expect it to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

There is no efficient way to seek lines. Only thing I can think of is using a RandomAccessFile, seeking a random possition and then reading the next 200(?) characters into an array. Then do the linebreak finding and form a String.

[doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)